# why isn't this rails database has_one relationship working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, simple-form, belongs-to, has-one

I have two models: User and Description.  All User's have one Description and all Descriptions belong to a User.  I created a form that creates a description, but when I tried to retrieve description data in a view, I couldn't.  I checked my database and the user_id column of the descriptions table is not updating.  I thought this should happen automatically with a has_one/belongs_to relationship.  How do I fix this so that the user_id field automatically gets filled with the user's id?

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :description
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :description
end
```

Here's my description model::

```
class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here's my description controller:

```
class DescriptionsController < ApplicationController

        def new
            @description = Description.new
            @current = current_user.id
        end
        def create
            #Description.create(description_params)
            @description = Description.create(description_params)
            redirect_to student_path
        end
        def index
        end

    private

    def description_params
      params.require(:description).permit(:skills, :looking_for, :my_idea, :user_id)
    end
end
```

And here is the view:

```
<div class="span6 offset3 text-center">
<h1>Edit your information</h1>

    <%= simple_form_for @description do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :skills %>
        <%= f.input :looking_for, :label => 'What help do you need?' %>
        <%= f.input :my_idea %>
        <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :value => @current %>
        <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I've tried removing user_id from accepted params - that does nothing.  I've also tried passing the user_id in using a hidden field - this did not work, but I also don't think it should be necesarry and i don't think it would be the right way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, the idea is that you'd submit the attributes for the `Description` model as *part* of the form for your `User` model. That doesn't appears to be what you're doing here.

If you don't want to do that, you should remove that line and in your controller do

`current_user.build_description(description_params)`

(or you can use `#create_description` if you want to initialize/save all at once).

For example

```
def create
  @description = current_user.create_description(description_params)
  redirect_to student_path
end
```

See the [Active Record Associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) for documentation for these `has_one` methods.